# Pandas tuples groupby aggregation

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, tuples

Certain columns of my data frame contain tuples. Whenever I do aggregation via group by that columns do not appear in the resulting data frame unless explicitly specified.

Example,

```py
df = pd.DataFrame()
df['A'] = [1, 2, 1, 2]
df['B'] = [1, 2, 3, 4]
df['C'] = map(lambda s: (s,), df['B'])
print df
   A  B     C
0  1  1  (1,)
1  2  2  (2,)
2  1  3  (3,)
3  2  4  (4,)
```

If I do the following way then the column `C` does not appear in aggregation

```py
print df.groupby('A').sum()
   B
A   
1  4
2  6
```

But if I specify it explicitly it appears as expected

```py
print df[['A', 'C']].groupby('A').sum()
        C
A        
1  (1, 3)
2  (2, 4)
```

Could you please tell me why the `C` column didn't appear in the first case?

I would like it to go by default.

Comment: did you not forget a `C` like in `df.groupby('A')['C'].sum()` ?

Comment: I might be definitely missing something but I don't know what exactly. OK, let me add an extra column `df['D'] = [5, 6, 7, 8]`. Then I would like the output of `df.groupby('A').sum()` to have all three columns `B`, `C` and `D` but I am getting `B` and `D` only not `C`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you aggregate by column `B`, not column `C`:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame()
df['A'] = [1, 2, 1, 2]
df['B'] = [1, 2, 3, 4]
df['C'] = map(lambda s: (s,), df['B'])
print df

df.at[0,'B'] = 10
print df
   A   B     C
0  1  10  (1,)
1  2   2  (2,)
2  1   3  (3,)
3  2   4  (4,)

print df.groupby('A').sum()
    B
A    
1  13
2   6

print df.groupby('A')['B'].sum()
1    13
2     6
Name: B, dtype: int64
```

Comment: Sorry, I didn't catch you. I can add an extra column `df['D'] = [5, 6, 7, 8]`. The output of `df.groupby('A').sum()` contains both `B` and `D` but not `C`. I would like to aggregate by all columns.

Comment: Column `A` is converted index, so aggregated can be column `B` and `C`. But column `C` is omited, because groupby [`sum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.sum.html) omit some columns.

Comment: You can check http://wesmckinney.com/blog/groupby-fu-improvements-in-grouping-and-aggregating-data-in-pandas/, part `New: Omitting "nuisance" columns`

Comment: Great! Is there a way not to omit columns in case a programmer knows what she is doing?

Comment: Hard question, I dont know way as prevent it. Maybe only you can specify aggregating column `df.groupby('A')['C'].sum()` and then [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html) output by columns with `df.groupby('A').sum()`.